# How to get the following output in asyncio gather

Tags: python, async-await

Is there a way I can get the as_completed results for both `result1` and `result2`
combined?

Expected Output

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Current Output

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Code

```
import asyncio

async def sleep(i):
    await asyncio.sleep(i)
    return i

async def main():
    result1 = [sleep(i) for i in [2, 1, 0]]
    result2 = [sleep(i) for i in [2, 1, 0]]

    result1Gathered = asyncio.as_completed(result1)
    result2Gathered = asyncio.as_completed(result2)

    result = await asyncio.gather(*result1Gathered, *result2Gathered)

    print(result)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because [`gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) returns the results as given to it.

What you want is not `gather` but to just loop through the results of [`as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed). You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to combine all the iterables:

```
from itertools import chain

...

async def main():
    result1 = [sleep(i) for i in [2, 1, 0]]
    result2 = [sleep(i) for i in [2, 1, 0]]

    result = [await i for i in asyncio.as_completed(chain(result1, result2))]

    print(result)
```

Result:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: thanks, so this will not block my event loop?

Comment: also can you explain why the gather does not work the way I thought it would? the one with `0` as arg should be finished first right? why aren't they first by default?

Comment: I know this was not part of the original question, but I would appreciate if you can answer this too, how would I deal with this if the awaitables are not of the same length? if I use zip_longest would None as fill value work?

Comment: @Jake Please see my edit